# db2 Query Is Taking Different Time In Diff Environments

Tags: linux, database, performance, db2

Query is taking different time in DEV and TEST environments. Same query in TEST environment is taking more time then in DEV environment.

OS= SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (on both).

DB= db2 10.5 (on both).

Ram= 32gb (on both).

CPU on DEV=

vendor_id       : IBM/S390
processors    : 8
bogomips per cpu: 14367.00

CPU on test:

vendor_id       : IBM/S390
processors    : 8
bogomips per cpu: 18115.00

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why query is slow on Test environment, while in DEV its running fine. Tables has same structure and same number of data.

Comment: Did you compare the query plans? (I have a feeling that you did not, so -- do that first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the difference is significant, so i will look first of missing indexes, reorgs and runstats. If all looks the same, then the load on the 2 environments should be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've done an explain both in both and the plans are the same; so you know you aren't missing any indexes.

And that the tables have exactly the same data in both environments.

Then all I can say is that SQL performance is heavily dependent on the run time environment.

Meaning # of active processes and the amount of free memory.

Unless you are the only user and both environments are set up exactly the same, I'd expect to see differences in query run-times.